# Swift. Changing multiple UIButtons with IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

So, I have 20 UI buttons on a single viewcontroller. I also have 2 other buttons there that will change the currentTitle or background color of different groups of those buttons. (for example, pressing one of those 2 buttons will change the color of 10 other buttons, while pressing the other button will change the background of 15 of those buttons.)

Am I doomed to having to create 20 different IBOutlets like:

@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

.

.

.

and then having to write an additional 25 lines of:

button1!.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal()

button2!.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal()

button3!.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal()

Surely theres an easier way to do this? I can't link more than one UI with IBOutlet, and changing the tags for the buttons don't do much either because I still have to write the darn things down 25 times regardless.

Is it possible to put those buttons into groups where I can write a single line of code to change ALL things in that group?

Comment: You can use a referencing outlet collection (array IBOutlet) rather than individual IBOutlets

Comment: How do I mutate all the objects in the array at once? The [UIButton] type doesn't have the setTitleColor property. Sorry, I'm a bit new at this.

Comment: You would need to loop through the array and set the title color on each button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your button tags in series like 101 to 125 and on click of any button perform this operation

```
for(UIButton *button in <parent view of buttons>.subviews){
   if(button.tag >= 101 && button.tag <= 125){
      button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal()
   }
}
```

**For Swift**

```
for subview in self.createBugView.subviews {

     if let button = subview as? UIButton {
        // this is a button
       if(button.tag >= 101 && button.tag <= 125){      
             button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: I want to execute the .setTitleColor command AFTER the user presses a button that changes color to red. I'll have another button that changes those buttons to blue, and another that changes the background color of those buttons. Are you saying I can accomplish those by putting those 3 buttons in the "parent view" of the other 20 buttons and then writing  out the subsequent code?

Comment: No need to put 3 different buttons on the "parent view" of other 20 buttons. What I understand, there is a view who contain 20 buttons with tag in series and 3 different buttons on other view to change color of 20 buttons. So simply click on these 3 buttons write following code and it will work surely.